# Basic of JSON Objects

Tags: json

I just learned the concept behind JSON objects and there use and I'll love to learn handling of JSON with Java and C++, does anybody have any knowledge about using JSON in the two languages and could provide some useful links and information to aid my way?

Answer (score 2):

I've found JSON in general to be great for quickly storing and re-loading large data structures for quick use between models (or saving information so you can pick up where you left off).  I've only ever used it in Python but http://www.json.org/ has a great list of JSON libraries for many languages